# I get this error message when I try to add a module to a course on my website using Sensei plugin

Tags: posts

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas01_data02/82/3603982/html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 2287

Comment: I seen the same error on a site I manage due to a different plugin. The problem seems to be that term queries return objects now instead of strings. The plugin needs updated to conform to the new standard.

Comment: You mean by updating the plugin the problem might get fixed?

Comment: Yes, if the plugin is updated by the author then it will likely be fixed. Certain term functions now return objects where as previously they returned strings. The plugin seems to expect a sting but it's given a WP_Term object. That makes me think that it's due to the changes WP made - and usually those are fixed by plugin authors quickly.